# How to: ask server about updates

Tags: c#, .net-core, microservices

My question is about a search of appropriate way of implementation. 
I have an application and I need to make it to check for updates. Actually we shouldn't pay attention for the reason of sending the message. It may not be a message about updates but something else. What is the best way to implement it?

Now it asks my REST service while starting but what if the application is working a long time and I need to inform the user about updates? Maybe message bus can help or there is any best practice?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify:
My client application asks service (REST) to check if there is any updates but I want to make the service to inform my client. So the question is what is the best way to send a message from the service to my client to inform about new application update.

Comment: What have you tried? What is failing? Your question is worded in a way that isn't very clear. I would recommend showing the effort what you've attempted thus far, and where that's gone wrong. I would also suggest you reword your question and make it **more clear** in what you're needing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your szenario I'd use a REST server and send a request every few hours. If you want your server to notify your client, SignalR should be a good choice.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/

Comment: Another way is to use a messaging pattern, and one of the messaging queue software, such as RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ.